# How to include more than one images in Alexa card

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an Alexa Skill and would like to response a Standard Card with images. Amazon said that only one image can be included in a card, but it seems that AccuWeather.com can have more than one images in a card.

[image of AccuWeather.com here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Pwv.png)

For the larger weather icon on the upper part of the card, it seems using the pre-defined smallImageUrl/ largeImageUrl. How about the smaller weather icons at the bottom of the card? Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this image is of the built-in Alexa whether skill rather than a skill from accuweather.com. Amazon's Alexa Skill API doesn't allow for more than one image in third-party skills, unfortunately.